Django: GET /getMessages// HTTP/1.1" 404 2987
I am following a Django tutorial video on how to create a simple chat room. When I want to create a new room, a pop-up alert says "An error occurred". Couldn't figure out what went wrong.
Errors:
home.html
room.html
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('<str:room>/', views.room, name='room'),
path('checkview', views.checkview, name='checkview')
> ]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from chat.models import Room, Message

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def room(request, room):
    return render(request, 'room.html')


def checkview(request):
    room = request.POST['room_name']
    username = request.POST['username']

    if Room.objects.filter(name=room).exists():
        return redirect('/'+room+'/?username='+username)
    else:
        new_room = Room.objects.create(name=room)
        new_room.save()
        return redirect('/'+room+'/?username='+username)

models.py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


# Create your models here.
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


class Message(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)






Remove the closing angle bracket in `path('checkview', views.checkview, name='checkview')

]`


can you share your html files with js scripts?


check the form in your template html file to make sure the form tag is added correctly. For example, it should look like this:


<form method="POST" action="/checkview">
 {% csrf_token %}
...
</form>



make change in urls:


path('checkview/', views.checkview, name='checkview'),

